# importdata command Matlab

Tags: matlab, importerror

Well I know this should be a pretty simple task, but I have been unable to use the importdata command. what I have is this

```
>> FILENAMES{j}
ans =
'L1S11_0_0.mat'

>> importdata(FILENAMES{j})
??? Error using ==> importdata at 136
Unable to open file.
```

The file is there because when I use the command in this way

```
>> importdata('L1S11_0_0.mat')
ans = 
           cycles: 0
             load: 0
          comment: 'Baseline'
        condition: 'Baseline'
        path_data: [1x252 struct]
  straingage_data: [1x1 struct]
        XRay_data: [1x1 struct]
```

It works perfectly.

I have +100 files to import and I cant simply write the names manually each time with every importdata command.

Can you say what could I be doing wrong?

By the way: I am using Matlab R2010a

Thanks

So adding more to the code I use, The way I populate the FILENAMES variable is

```
C{1,i} = textscan(fid1, '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',1,'delimiter',';');
FILENAMES=[];
FILENAMES=[FILENAMES;C{1,i}{1,7}];
%Successively reads the rows until it find a row without a Data File
%(Column 7)
while isempty(C{1,i}{1,7})== false
i=i+1;
C{1,i} = textscan(fid1, '%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s',1,'delimiter',';');
FILENAMES=[FILENAMES;C{1,i}{1,7}];
end
```

I have checked many times and there are no typos in the files names

Comment: 1) When you type `class(FILENAMES{j})` at Matlab command line, what do you get? 2) When you type `dir` at your command line, do you see the `.mat` file in the list?

Comment: The FILENAMES is a cell class variable. And yes the file is there

Comment: Sorry to repeat the question, but I asked for the class of `FILENAMES{j}`, not the class of `FILENAMES`.

Comment: Ah ok, `class(FILENAMES{j})` is "char"

Comment: Good, so is not a type mismatch. Now, if you type at Matlab command prompt, `strcmp(FILENAMES{j}, 'L1S11_0_0.mat')`, what do you get?

Comment: I tried the matlab documentation example  `myfilename = sprintf('file%d.txt', k);
  mydata{k} = importdata(myfilename);  `      And it is also not working. It should be returning a "1" but I don't understand why it doesn't

Comment: `strcmp` returns 1 (i.e. `true`) if and only if the strings are equal. That says that actually (for that value  of `j` index) the content of the cell array is not actually the file name. Please look for typos, like replacing the digit `1` with low case L `l`, replacing underscores`_` with spaces ` `, supplemental spaces in name etc.

Comment: I am completely positive that there is no typo. I tried assigning the name of the file to another variable (nombre) and run the command "importdata(nombre)" and it doesn't work. Also the comparison between _nombre_ and the name of the file gives "0" as result

Comment: So running at command line `nombre = 'L1S11_0_0.mat'; strcmp(nombre, 'L1S11_0_0.mat')` returns `0`? This is really unbelievable...

Comment: Could you paste the code that populates the `FILENAMES` cell array with values?

Comment: Yes the file name passed to importdata differs in the ''. So one is 'L1S11_0_0.mat' and the other is L1S11_0_0.mat. I will add the code to populate FILENAMES in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the mistake is the fact that the requested `FILENAME{j}` contains single quotes in the string. Single quotes are allowed in file names for many filesystems, so the requested file name is considered valid and tried for opening. Of course, the file named `L1S11_0_0.mat` is not the same as the file named `'L1S11_0_0.mat'`, hence the error.

A simple way to test this is at the Matlab prompt:

```
>> FILENAMES{j}

ans =

'L1S11_0_0.mat'

>> FILENAMES{j} = 'L1S11_0_0.mat'; FILENAMES{j}

ans =

L1S11_0_0.mat
```

*Later edit:*

A simple way to remove *all* the single quotes from the file name before importing it would be:

```
>> importdata(FILENAMES{j}(FILENAMES{j} ~= ''''))
```

Comment: That is exactly the problem. when I use command `importdata(myfilename)` the file name pased to the function of importdata is 'L1S11_0_0.mat'. If I use `importdata('L1S11_0_0.mat')` the file name pased to the function is L1S11_0_0.mat  (which is the correct one). Any ideas how could I fix this??

Comment: @Tarigarma Okay, now you have a way of removing the single quotes. Be careful, it removes all of them; if you have any files that will have single quotes in their proper name (though unlikely), you won't be able to import them like this.

Comment: Thank you, luckily none of the filenames have the character '' in them and for the moment this looks more straight forward that transforming FILENAMES in extra command lines. Anyway I am still pretty confused as to why this problem appeared in the first place, since I tried the code in another machine and it worked perfectly...

Comment: The same code may work differently on different input or different operating system. The source of single quotes seems to be the content of the file open as `fid1`. Now, if the operating system of the other machine considers the single quotes as a path grouping char -- between such delimiters the paths are allowed to have white spaces -- then on that machine it would be no problem to open that file. On this machine (I suspect a Win7 one, right?) the path grouping char is the double quote. So you wouldn't have any problem running `importdata('"L1S11_0_0.mat"')`  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
f=load('L1S11_0_0.mat');
```

instead of:

```
importdata('L1S11_0_0.mat');
```

?